# Open and Close page between certain days

Tags: php, mysql, variables, days

I have googled it but I didn't found that type of code. I want a php code that will read a value that is the number of days that the access to a page will be approved.

For example, if today is the first opening of the page and the value of the days from the next opening will be 20, so, from today, we will add 20 days and then the page will be open again.

I better example is this one, we have a recruitment, the recruitment will be open for 2 days, and then, after those two days will be closed during 20, and then will open again(over and over again). But i want to define this two variables, the recruitment open time, and the time between the recruitment.

Other simpler function is that if I define a manual recruitment, it will open and when I close it, the recruitment will start counting 20 days from the day when I close it.

Comment: And what exactly is your question? Did you tried anything yet?

Comment: [Please don’t use signatures in your posts](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures)

Comment: Hi peterm, i'm new in php, and i don't have any ideia how to do it...

Comment: @Fred I'm as new as you to PHP but this might be a good place to start http://css-tricks.com/snippets/php/change-graphics-based-on-season/

Comment: Thanks Adam, i will check that ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know any link, but ur code can be something like this. Please check the links, the functions are self-explanatory.

```
$lastRecDay = "2013-01-11"; // this will be coming from ur db


// create a date object
$date = new DateTime($lastRecDay);
//add 20 days to it
$date->add(new DateInterval('P10D')); // ur date is 20 from last day

//its 20 days+ since the posting
if( $date->format('U') <= strtotime('now'))
{
 // your code re-open goes here
}
```

Comment: Thanks cjg. I will adivse if this works.

Comment: It's working perfectly, i will right the all code that i want to use, and then if this fit's there i will post here. Thanks so much!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so it sounds like you need to monitor the following variables

```
Open date
Display days
Interval days
End date
```

Then you do it like this

```
create a page
enter the first open date
enter the days to be displayed
enter the days between closing and re-opening (interval)
enter the end date
```

then calculate if it is to be displayed by

```
if (today < enddate ) {
  if (today >= opendate) and (today <= opendate + displaydays)
    show
  else if (today > opendate + displaydays)
    opendate = today + interval
}
```

The question now is how do you store your data?  I imagine this is easiest in a db, but you can probably do it inside a file as well.

Will expand on the instructions when I know your storage type.

Comment: Hi Christian! Thanks for your reply. It will be in db :)

Comment: This question is closed now Fred, sorry :s  But use the logic in my answer to build your PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

In php, you can use [date_add](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-add.php) to add the date. And in mysql also there is [date_add](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add). That should solve your problem I guess.

Comment: Thanks cjg! But, anyone can give my a link or any ideia of how can i do this: read the last day of an open recruitment, add 20 days(this is the variable of the days between the recruitments) and if the last day plus 20 days is "today" it will open the recruitment again, but my problem is how can i add days? It will have problems because of the months... i guess... Sorry for my English and Thanks guys ;)